# Back substitute example

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$ 3f + 280y = 1 $$

euclidean algorithm

$$ 280 = 3\cdot 93 + 1  $$
$$ 3 = 1 \cdot 3 $$

Back sub

$$ 1 = 280 + 3(-93) $$

my question is why a negative sign for 93? since in the euclidean algorithm the 93 is a positive one.

Comment: Because in $280 = 3\cdot 93 + 1$ you moved $3\cdot 93$ on the other side: $280 - 3\cdot 93 = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Euclidean Algorithm finding the solutions to
$$3f+280y=1$$
is equivalent to finding the solutions to
$$3a-280b=1$$
And it's not abnormal to have solutions that are negative since solutions to the gcd equation are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

There's a negative sign because $1=280+3(93)$ is false.